# Using promises in mongoose for passport authentication

Tags: node.js, mongoose, promise, passport.js

```
var LocalStrategy = require('passport-local').Strategy;
var User = require('../models/user');

module.exports = function(passport){
  passport.use('local-signup', new LocalStrategy({
    usernameField: 'email',
    passwordField: 'password',
    passReqToCallback: true
  },
  function(req, email, password, done){

    User.findOne({'local.username': email}).exec()
      .then(function(user) {
        console.log(user);
        if(user){
          return done(null, false, {message: 'Username already taken!'});
        }
        else{
          var newUser = new User();

          newUser.local.username = email;
          newUser.local.password = password;

          return newUser.save();
        }
      })
      .then(function(user) {
        console.log('DEBUG DEBUG DEBUG');
        done(null, user);
      })
      .catch(function(err) {
        done(err);
      });
  }
  ));

  passport.serializeUser(function(user, done) {
    done(null, user.id);
  });

  passport.deserializeUser(function(userid, done) {
      User.findById(userid).exec()
        .then(function(user) {
          done(user);
        });
  });
};
```

In my case the debug log always be printed, whether return `newUser.save()` is called or not.
Is it possible to make the debug log only be printed when return `newUser.save()` is called?

Btw I'm using passportJS for authentication things and for the promise I'm override mongoose default promise with global es6 promise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mean like this? Sorry if there are extra brackets or parenthesis. I edited in the text box. :(

```
   User.findOne({'local.username': email}).exec()
      .then(function(user) {

        if(user){
          return done(null, false, {message: 'Username already taken!'});
        }
        else{
          var newUser = new User();

          newUser.local.username = email;
          newUser.local.password = password;

          return newUser.save()
              .then(function(){
                  console.log('DEBUG DEBUG DEBUG');              
                  done(null, user);      
              })
        }
      })
      .catch(function(err) {
        done(err);
      });
  }
  ));
```

Comment: I agree with your solution. It uses the promise returned from the `.save()` method which works just as well and may be preferential for some people's javascript coding styles. Needless to say I like the cut of your jib! Have an upvote!

Comment: Your solution is work, but if I put newUser.save().then() in else scope. The code will like callback style.

It will be more cleaner if the promise being chained right? rather than putting it in else scope?

Comment: Unfortunately it is necessary in this case. However you can remove the `else` and it will  help reduce nesting.

Comment: Ohh okay. so in this case, it isimpossible to do chained promise?

Comment: Youre wanting to conditionally chain, which is not how chaining works. So no. :(

Comment: Okay thank you @PatrickMotard. Do u have any good resource / video tutorial about es6 promises?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/121881/discussion-between-patrick-motard-and-kim).

Answer (score 1):

Just put your debug message in a function in `newUser.save()`

```
User.findOne({'local.username': email}).exec()
  .then(function(user) {
    console.log(user);
    if(user){
      return done(null, false, {message: 'Username already taken!'});
    }
    else{
      var newUser = new User();

      newUser.local.username = email;
      newUser.local.password = password;

      return newUser.save(function() {
        console.log('SAVED!');
        console.log('DEBUG DEBUG DEBUG');
      });
    }
  })
  .then(function(user) {
    done(null, user);
  })
```

Comment: I agree with your solution. We posted nearly at the same time. Your method uses a callback, which is fine, but I believe promises will work as well, and are more in line with his requirements of using ES6 promises. Either way, have an upvote!